# How to fetch the amount of results Google returns when you query "site: example.com"?

Tags: php, api, symfony, google-search

I know this question is asked a lot, but all the answers are outdated because the Search API is disabled by Google.

Google used to have a Search API and with that API it was possible to search in Google using an API. Most answers on StackOverflow link to the deprecated documentation of that API, but because Google turned off that API, I can't solve the issue using the API.

I tried to fix the issue by crawling the google result page and fetching the count from the "about x results found in y seconds" text. But as far as I know, this is restricted because of Google Policy.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en

Anybody has an idea how to fix this issue without breaking the Google Policy? I work with the Symfony Framework in PHP, but I won't mind it if I need to load in a javascript library or a command line tool?

Answer (score 1):

Now that the Search API is gone, it is no longer possible to lawfully scrape Google's general search results.

From the title to your question, it appears that you're looking to scrape a specific site. That can still be done lawfully using the Custom Search JSON/Atom API at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview.

Comment: As far as I understand I have to register the specific site to my Google Search Console right? I don't have the site registered to my Google Search Console and that won't be possible. Because this check is for an application which checks existing websites of prospects on quality. But correct me if I'm wrong, in that case I could use the Custom Search JSON/Atom API.

Comment: @RobertoGeuke That's correct. You can not programmatically set the search domains using Google Custom Search API. The best bet for doing something like that lawfully is using Microsoft's Bing API (now part of Azure). You can learn about it at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/directory/search/.

Comment: It's a shame because Bing isn't as widely used as Google, so the result won't be as useful. But all the extra information will help, so thank you. I will go to my technical manager with this information and see what he thinks.